# Confusion about Renderscript

Tags: android, renderscript

My question basically is should I be doing my calculations on `uchar4`s or `float4`s ?

From my understanding a `char` will take values from 0-255, so will a float right?

So here are 2 version of my code, old one and new (which do simple edge detection).

Old:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(foo.bar)

rs_allocation inPixels;
int height;
int width;
int threeBythree[];

void root(const uchar4 *in, uchar4 *out, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    float3 pixel = convert_float4(in[0]).rgb;

    if(x==0 || x==239 || y==0 || y==269){
        pixel.rb = 0;
        pixel.g = 255;
    }else{ //do image processing here

        float3 pixelNH = convert_float4(rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inPixels, x+1, y)).rgb;
        float3 pixelNV = convert_float4(rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inPixels, x, y+1)).rgb;

        int grayAvg = (pixel.r + pixel.g + pixel.b)/3;
        int grayAvgNH = (pixelNH.r + pixelNH.g + pixelNH.b)/3;
        int grayAvgNV = (pixelNV.r + pixelNV.g + pixelNV.b)/3;

        int edgeOperatorValue = 2*grayAvg - grayAvgNH - grayAvgNV;

        if(edgeOperatorValue < 0){
            edgeOperatorValue = -1 * edgeOperatorValue;
        };

        pixel.r = edgeOperatorValue;
        pixel.g = edgeOperatorValue;
        pixel.b = edgeOperatorValue;
    };

    out->xyz = convert_uchar3(pixel);
}
```

The above produces this:

http://s9.postimg.org/9plpvjwun/Screenshot_2015_08_09_17_54_43.png

Which kinda makes sense.

The New:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.apps.foo.bar)

rs_allocation inPixels;
int height;
int width;

uchar4 RS_KERNEL root(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {

  uchar4 pixel = in.rgba;

  if(x==0 || x==width || y==0 || y==height){
      pixel.rb = 0;
      pixel.g = 255;
  }else{ //do image processing here
      uchar4 pixelNH = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inPixels, x+1, y);
      uchar4 pixelNV = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inPixels, x, y+1);

      int grayAvg = (pixel.r + pixel.g + pixel.b)/3;
      int grayAvgNH = (pixelNH.r + pixelNH.g + pixelNH.b)/3;
      int grayAvgNV = (pixelNV.r + pixelNV.g + pixelNV.b)/3;

      int edgePixelValue = abs(2 * grayAvg - grayAvgNH + grayAvgNV);
      pixel.rgb = edgePixelValue;
  };

  return pixel;
}
```

Which is the same mathematical formula, just written in a different way.

Produces this:

http://s24.postimg.org/8kgg1a4v9/Screenshot_2015_08_09_17_55_35.png

Which it looks like a grayscaled image.

I am working with rgb images and I need to average each pixel first. I don't need to do each channel separately.

Thanks

Comment: In first code snippet you write _2 * grayAvg - grayAvgNH - grayAvgNV_ , in latter one _2 * grayAvg - grayAvgNH + grayAvgNV_ . Is it intentional to add and not subtract grayAvgNV?

Comment: Also, I hope you can see that the conditional is broken.

Comment: @harism the second one is the correct. must be a typo

Comment: @user15860 - so, do you still get incorrect results after correcting he typo?

Comment: @MiloslawSmyk Apologies for the late response. Ok I got it! it seems my maths was wrong. The first one is wrong, and the second one is correct. thanks! it was a typo